# How do I detect simultaneous key presses?

Tags: python, game-physics, keyboard-events, pynput

Context: I'm trying to make a python script that detects single key presses for WASD and simultaneous key presses for (w and a), (w and d), (s and a), (s and d). I'm using the pynput library and I've already made a script that mostly works the way I want.

Problem: When I run the script and press two keys, it detects a single key press immediately before it detects the simultaneous key press. I think this happens because it is impossible for me to hit two keys exactly at the same time.

How do y'all circumvent this? Thanks in advance.

```
from pynput import keyboard

key_events = set()


def on_press(key):
    try:
        if key.char.lower() in ['w', 'a', 's', 'd']:
            key_events.add(key.char.lower())
            if 'w' in key_events and 'd' in key_events:
                print("rightup")
            elif 'w' in key_events and 'a' in key_events:
                print("leftup")
            elif 's' in key_events and 'd' in key_events:
                print("rightdown")
            elif 's' in key_events and 'a' in key_events:
                print("leftdown")
            elif key.char.lower() == 'w':
                print("up")
            elif key.char.lower() == 'd':
                print("right")
            elif key.char.lower() == 's':
                print("down")
            elif key.char.lower() == 'a':
                print("left")
    except AttributeError:
        pass


def on_release(key):
    try:
        if key.char.lower() in ['w', 'a', 's', 'd']:
            key_events.discard(key.char.lower())
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False


listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release)
listener.start()
listener.join()
```

Comment: You track both key pressed and key releases. Two keys are pressed simultaneously if the second key is pressed while the first key is still pressed within some short time interval.

Comment: You probably need to add an async delay that traps keypresses and waits for .1 seconds (or something) before returning the final keypress.  Other wise this is all synchronous making it impossible.